# .NET - Omit Fields from JSON Web Service Call

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services

I'm working on a .NET application for my company to interact with the Nutshell CRM.  They have documentation provided for their JSON API [here](https://www.nutshell.com/api/detail/class_core.html).  I'm slowly building out all the classes in my application, but I've run into the issue of only needing to update one field on a call, but having the application include every field that I have on that class.

So for a condensed example of the editLead method, where I'm only modifying the `customFields`:

Nutshell documentation states that all fields are optional.  My classes are set up as the following, where my custom fields in Nutshell are Division, Product, Country:

```
    public class editLead
    {
          public Customfields customFields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customfields
    {
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT (adding more code):

```
    [DataContract(Name = "params")]
    public class EditLeadParams
    {
        public string leadId { get; set; }
        public editLead lead { get; set; }
        public string rev { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using RestSharp to make the following call:

```
            var editleadclient = new RestClient();
            Method editleadMethod = new Method();
            editleadMethod = Method.POST;
            var editleadrequest = new RestRequest(editleadMethod);
            editleadrequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            editleadclient.BaseUrl = new Uri(apiuri);
            editleadrequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, apikey);

            leadJSON.EditLeadParams lead1 = new leadJSON.EditLeadParams()
            {
                leadId = foundlead[0],
                lead = new leadJSON.editLead()
                {
                    customFields = new leadJSON.Customfields()
                    {
                        Division = "AMERICAS",
                    }
                },
                rev = foundlead[1],
            };

            leadJSON.EditLeadRequest editreq = new leadJSON.EditLeadRequest()
            {

                @params = lead1,
                method = "editLead",
            };

            editleadrequest.AddBody(editreq);
            IRestResponse editResponse = editleadclient.Execute(editleadrequest);
```

If I only want to update the Division, it will use the following JSON `{"customFields":{"Division":"AMERICAS","Product":null,"Country":null}}`, and overwrite the Product and Country fields and make them blank.  However, if I comment out the `Product` and `Country`, in the `Customfields` definition, it will update the `Division` and leave the `Product` and `Country` alone.

Is there another way to define these classes so that I can have it all defined, but only update what needs to be?

Comment: What you're not showing here is how you actually interact with the service in question.  If you're serializing a class, all fields will be present in the serialized result.  But you might not need to serialize the class, you might be able to serialize an anonymous object derived from the class.  Can you show where the actual problem is happening?

Comment: If your editing an existing entity should you not retrieve it from their service using the get lead, update it and then send it back thus not blanking the items you don't want to edit?

Comment: @David, I've added more code.

Comment: @DotNetHitMan, I do believe that would work, but it would require me to completely map the whole API, which I was hoping to only do the areas I need, as it will be a large task to do it all.  If it's necessary, then I'll suck it up and do it, but I hoped it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Boone: If you only want to update one field, can you construct the request with an anonymous object instead of a defined one?  Something like: `new { Division = "AMERICAS" }`  (Or something more involved to wrap the values in a larger hierarchy.  It's kind of difficult to follow the structure here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declaration:**

```
//JsonSerializer.cs
public static class JsonSerializer
{
    public static string Serialize(object target, bool ignoreNulls = true)
    {
        var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        if (ignoreNulls)
        {
            javaScriptSerializer.RegisterConverters(new[] 
            {
                new NullExclusionConverter(target)
            });
        }
        return javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(target);
    }
}


//NullExclusionConverter.cs
public class NullExclusionConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    private readonly Type _type;

    public NullExclusionConverter(object target)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
        }
        this._type = target.GetType();
    }



    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get 
        { 
            return new[] { this._type };
        }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return result;
        }
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            //Use propertyInfo.Name to exclude a specific property name
            if (propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            result.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objectToSerialize);
```

Add a reference to *System.Web.Extensions*

Comment: I'm trying this, but ran into a couple things.  I think instead of `string jsonString = JsonSerializer.ToJson(objectToSerialize);`, you meant `string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objectToSerialize);` - correct? And when I use that, `jsonString` is getting prints to the Console, correctly, although still including `"Product":null` & `"Country":null`, but when I examine the call in Fiddler, it's inserting a `\\`` before each `"`

Comment: Correct, it was a typo. Updated the post. Post the value of jsonString that you are getting.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(jsonString) prints: `"{"leadId":"10797","lead":{"customFields":{"Division":"AMERICAS","Product":null,"Country":null}},"rev":"14"}"` but Fiddler shows the call using `"{\"leadId\":\"10797\",\"lead\":{\"customFields\":{\"Division\":\"AMERICAS\",\"Product\":null,\"Country\":null}},\"rev\":\"14\"}"`

Comment: And I'm making the assumption that I should be replacing my previous `editleadrequest.AddBody(editreq);` with `editleadrequest.AddBody(jsonString);`

Comment: It turns out that RestSharp's AddBody method is trying to reformat the string to JSON, even though it's already in the correct form, which is why I was getting the random `\\` marks

Answer (score 1):

I am leaving my initial answer because it does return only non-null properties as a Json string.  However here is your answer when using RestSharp.

**On your request add:**

```
editleadrequest.JsonSerializer.Options = new SerializerOptions()
{
    SkipNullProperties = true
};
```

Comment: That looks simple enough, but Options doesn't appear to be available to me.  I just made sure my RestSharp was up to date, and it is - v105.2.3.  I Googled it, and found [this fork](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/404/files) - but I don't know how to implement it - or figure out if it was added to the official release

Comment: After searching a while, I found that it JSON.NET handles nulls in a similar way to this, so I'm using it to serialize the data now.  Thank you, Martin, for helping me and leading me in the right direction.